pandas dataframe index to html merged cell
I have a pandas dataframe like as below
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'A': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
    'B': [10, 10, 20, 20, 30],
    'C': [100, 101, 200, 201, 300],
    'D': ['X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Z'],
    'E': ['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Beta', 'Gamma', 'Gamma'],
    'F': [1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

I already referred the post here. But this may not help with my objective as I have more than 300 files
My objective is to do the below

I have more than 300 html files for which I would like to apply this formatting.

The problem is, when I try to index columns (for the purpose of merge), the layout goes haywire and results in an ugly output as shown below
res = df.set_index(['A', 'B','C'])
s = res.style
s = s.set_properties(
        **{'border': '1px black solid !important','font-size': '10pt'}).set_table_attributes(
        'style="border-collapse:collapse"').set_table_styles([{
        'selector': '.col_heading',
        'props': 'background-color:black; font-size:9pt; color: white; border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px black solid !important;'
        }])
output = s.to_html("table.html",escape=False,index=False)


Instead, I would like to get an output like below. One good thing is, I always know that it is only columns A and B that has to be merged.

update - Sample input
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Project_name': ['ABC', 'ABC', 'DEF', 'DEF', 'XYZ'],
    'Application': ['App1', 'App1', 'App2', 'App2', 'App3'],
    'Past_products': ['P1', 'P1', 'P2', 'P2', 'P3'],
    'Current_Product': ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5'],
    'Recommendation_type': ['Type1', 'Type1', 'Type2', 'Type2', 'Type3'],
    'Rec_products': ['R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4', 'R5']
})


rowspan="2" on the A & B items (Assuming there are always 2 options in the rest of the columns)? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69403679/how-to-use-multiple-rowspan-in-a-table

@Paulie_D No, there will not be two. It could be anything from 1 to 12.

you can always create own string with HTML and write it as normal file - instead of using .to_html()

maybe it needs to reset index - to convert it to normal columns?

here is source code for html formater in pandas. You may try to read it to see how it works, or you can use it to create own formater which will add indexes in expected way.

You can tweak it by overrinding the original thead, using replace_with from beautifulsoup:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS, Tag

soup = BS(s.to_html(), "html.parser")

thead, tr = Tag(name="thead"), Tag(name="tr")
    
for _tr in soup.find("thead").find_all("tr")[::-1]:
    for tag in _tr.find_all("th"):
        if tag.text != "\xa0":  # `&nbsp;:` pandas' placeholder
            tr.append(tag)
else:
    thead.append(tr)
    _ = soup.find("thead").replace_with(thead)

NB: Your Styler can (or must?) be simplified this way. And here is how to make an html file.


May I know how do you check for the specific columns to be updated and also it should be merged only when values are repeated right? What does \xa0 mean?

It’s all there in the answer, just give it a try ;)

I get an error like below - `AttributeError  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_17156\3112311710.py in <cell line: 7>()
5 thead, tr = Tag(name="thead"), Tag(name="tr")
6
----> 7 for _tr in soup.find("thead").find_all("tr")[::-1]:
8     for tag in _tr.find_all("th"):
9         if tag.text != "\xa0":  #  : pandas' placeholder
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'  Could this be because one of my non-index columns containsNone` as a value. But None is a valid value in my real time data. can help?

If you can update your example with a reproducible one, I'll be happy to help ;)

I provided an updated sample input at the bottom of my post. Even though I index using three columns - project_name, Application and past_products, it only merges the 1st two columns and the past_products remains as is. I want the columns that I set as index to be merged when there are repeating values.

I can't reproduce the error with the updated example. Maybe it's due to how you're using the code.
